# Critical r value after false discovery rate (FDR) p correction

Tags: r, correlation, false-discovery-rate

I would like to calculate a new threshold for my significance level based on the False Discovery Rate correction. 
I have a matrix of 100 x 100 with correlation coefficients. Each coefficient was calculated with 60 data points, I accept the alpha of 0.05.

```
# Here I generate a random matrix with correlation coefficients between 0 and 1
my_matrix <- matrix(runif(100*100), nrow = 100, ncol = 100)

# This function will return critical r value based on my alpha and number of observations (n)
critical_r <- function(n, alpha = .05) {
  df <- n - 2
  critical_t <- qt(alpha / 2, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
  critical_r_value <- sqrt((critical_t ^ 2) / ((critical_t ^ 2) + df))
  return(critical_r_value)
}

# Using this function, I calculate critical r value 
critical_threshold_cor <- critical_r(n = 60, alpha = 0.05)
> critical_threshold_cor
[1] 0.2542043 # for example

# Now, from my_matrix, I remove all correlations that are not significant
my_matrix[abs(my_matrix) < abs(critical_threshold_cor)] <- NA
```

The challenge here is, that before removing all insignificant correlations from my_matrix, I apply FDR correction and calculate the corrected alpha.

I am aware of the function `p.adjust` in base r, but it accepts p values and returns corrected p values. It is not exactly what I need.

Comment: This procedure looks strange to me: why do you need to control for FDR after you control for FDR?

Comment: I want to remove insignificant correlations. If I don't apply FDR correction, I remove all correlations, which alphas are greater than 0.05. 
But I have a matrix with lots of correlation coefficients, so before removing insignificant calculations, I should change (decrease) my alpha to consider the type I error. 
The question is simple, how to calculate new critical correlation value, threshold between significant and non-significant correlations.

Comment: Just to be clear, you shouldn't remove before calculating FDR. If you are aware of this, then the only thing you need to do is to use qvalue package to get q value (Storey's method) or pass in BH to p.adjust as the method for BH FDR correction.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I will test both methods just now...

Comment: I tried but I get wired results, is it possible to provide me with a two line code for that? Maybe I am missing something really obvious...

Comment: For each correlation you may extract a p-value: `cor.test(x,y)$p.value`. You save them as a vector (100x100 length). Then you apply `p.adjust(vector, method="fdr")`. These are FDR-corrected p-values. You need to do nothing else.However, this article may give you some insights on what can be wrong with your vector of p-values before the adjustment. http://varianceexplained.org/statistics/interpreting-pvalue-histogram/ Your strategy of decreasing alpha reminds me of FWER, not FDR.

Comment: I agree, this would be one of possible solutions. However, I don't have a matrix of p values. Ok, I could calculate it, since I know n. But this is not what I want. I am sure there is someone, who can provide me with a one-liner that calculates critical correlation coefficient value, which considers changes in alpha. It must be very simple, but my statistical background is simply not enough to come up with this equation.

Comment: @JerryTheForester p-value is monotonically dependent on the critical value, they are kind of interchangeble (at least in this case). What exactly change in alpha you want to introduce? alpha divided by the number of tests? I look at your proposed procedure and it either does not make any sense or is too smart for my understanding.

Comment: Maybe the procedure is not well described. The idea is to remove all insignificant correlation coefficients from the matrix. Using the critical_r function (see above), I can easily calculate critical correlation coefficient value, so I remove all values, which are smaller than my critical r value.

Comment: (continued) However, if I want to consider changes in p values due to multiple testing and again remove all insignificant, I can simply calculate new threshold. So, I need corrected alpha, which will not be 0.05 anymore, but less, maybe 0.001, depends on the number of tests. 
The corrected alpha will then be inserted into critical_r function and new threshold for significant correlations will be calculated.

Comment: You do not need corrected alpha and you do not need a critical value calculation (r does it for you once it makes cor.test). I'd recommend you to read this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate .

Comment: Let’s demonstrate my question with another example. I have a vector of 10 correlations, which were calculated using 60 observations.  
V = c(0.25, 0.00 , 0.46, 0.80, 0.64, 0.32, 0.25, 0.32, 0.50, 0.15)
The vector of corresponding p values is below: 
P = c(0.044, 1.000, 0.0002, 0.00001, 0.00001, 0.0126, 0.0448, 0.0126,0.00005,0.2526)
Based on my P vector, I can see that there are 2 correlations insignificant.

Comment: (continued) If I now apply > p.adjust(P, method = "BH"), I get new vector of corrected p values 
P_adjusted = c(0.056, 1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.021, 0.056, 0.021, 0.000, 0.280)
Is it correct if I now say that, considering adjusted p values, I have only 6 significant correlations?

Comment: @JerryTheForester Yeap, that's the correct inference IMHO. You dont need to pre-filter your correlation values based on critical values. However, this procedure relies on the fact that you have true H0 in your dataset, at least some, so the correction using the whole dataset will be much more efficient.

Comment: OK, so that’s good news. In the example with 10 values, critical r after p correction was 0.27 (visual determination). So my goal is to derive the equation that will calculate this critical r (after p adjustment)

Comment: OK, now we've turned back to the wrong road again, but I hope you got the idea and will be able to finish the inference.